# .htaccess - add language sub directory by default "sv/" (redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Trying to orientate myself through the .htaccess jungle, I've now narrated down my rewrite problems to one - adding a language suffix upon entering the page / typing in an address that doesn't have such one.

For example: a visitor types `mysite.com/kontakt`. This should take them to the default language of the site, i.e. `mysite.com/sv/kontakt`. Or, just typing in `mysite.com` should take him/her to `mysite.com/sv/`.

I'm developing this site locally using MAMP, and the site is located in a subdirectory, and here's the tricky part... How do I sort this out in the .htaccess file?

Current code used:

```
RewriteBase /mysite/  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(sv|en)  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sv/$1 [L,R=301]
```

And that takes me from `localhost/mysite/` to `localhost/sv/`. Not exactly right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mysite/

RewriteRule ^(?!(?:sv|en)/)(.*)$ sv/$1 [R=301,L]
```

1. This needs to be placed into .htaccess file into **/mysite/** folder.
2. If accessing `localhost/mysite/sv` without trailing slash, the rule will redirect it to `localhost/mysite/sv/sv` as it expects that the language part (`sv` or `en`) will be followed by the slash `/`.

**P.S.**
And look into setting up a VirtualHost -- then there will be much less (if none at all) of such "tricky parts" with accessing your website via `http://localhost/mysite/sv/kontakt` (I'm sure you will agree, that `http://mysite.dev/sv/kontakt` sounds and looks better).

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot LazyOne! Yes, I should be looking into setting up VirtualHost, but for the client showcase this week I need to get it working in a subdirectory as the live site will use that structure as well.